# Moving scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

Ok i have a div where there are messages from other users. I want that when they type something, that if the div is overflowing, the scrollbar goes to the bottom of the div I have tried this:

```
$('div').animate({scrollTop: $( $( '#final' ) ).offset().top}, 1000);
```

but i hace this error:

enviar.js:10  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

the test page:

```
<body background="fondos/fondo-inicio.jpg"">
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="inicio.php">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="paginaad.php">Administracion</a></li>
<li><a href="comentarios.php">Reporta</a></li>
<ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
<li><a href="#about">Sobre mi</a></li>
<li><a href="salir.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
<div id="contenedor"><span id="final"></span></div>
<input type="text" id="mensaje" name="mensaje" />
<button id="boton">Enviar</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Try it like this $('div').animate({scrollTop: $('#final').offset().top}, 1000);

Comment: No, sorry doesnt work is the same error

Comment: Post a fiddle of your full code. Make one on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to update the scroll position when you append the content.

This code works,and the essential part is the updatePos() function that i have added in

Whether you use php or otherwise, this is the bit that will make the difference.

You can use your original code and append the updatePos() but this is for example purposes (obviously i don't have access to your db)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#boton').on('click', function() {
    var content = $('#mensaje').val();
    $('#contenedor').append(content + '<br>');
    $('#final').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#contenedor').offset().top
    }, 1000);
    $('#mensaje').val('');
    updatePos();

  });


});

$(function() {
  $('#mensaje').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keycode == 13) {

      var content = $('#mensaje').val();
      $('#contenedor').append(content + '<br>');
      $('#mensaje').val('');
      updatePos();


    }
  });


  function updatePos() {
    var element = document.getElementById("contenedor");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;

  }



});
```

```css
#contenedor {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid!important;
  border-width: 3px!important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  top: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #07B3D1;
}

#mensaje {
  width: 20%;
  height: 6%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 30.2%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #07B3D1;
}

#boton {
  width: 5%;
  min-width: 75px;
  height: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #07B3D1;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 30%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  font-size: 100%;
}

#boton:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 0 #FFFFFF;
}

#final {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body background="fondos/fondo-inicio.jpg">
  <ul>

    <div id="contenedor"> <span id="final"></span></div>
    <input type="text" id="mensaje" name="mensaje">

    <button id="boton">Enviar</button>



  </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I have applied the function to my code and works great, Tahnk you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You provided the following code:

```
$('div').animate({scrollTop: $( $( '#final' ) ).offset().top}, 1000);
```

Which looks as though you've wrapped the `#final` element in two jQuery wrappers. Remove the duplicate `$()` and it should work as expected. It's undefined because it can't parse a jQuery object from another jQuery object. Here's the corrected code:

```
$('div').animate({
  scrollTop: $('#final').offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Comment: read the comments. I already told the op to do that. Still the same error

Comment: My apologies, Rachel. I jumped the gun on that one, thanks for the heads up. :)

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/m0ktL4hy/) i don't know why the result looks like this but in my page looks very good...